# IndexError: list index out of range - cannot reason the logic

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I asked before about this code and got some useful answers, but I wanted to add one more step which gives me an error. the code generates a set of cosine waves, then sums them all.
here is the code:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
freq=[]
x=linspace(-4000,4000,8001)
sum=0
for i in range(1,121,1):
    freq.append(cos(2*pi*i*(x/8001)))
    sum=(sum + freq[i])/i

plot(x,sum)
show()
```

with this code, I get the error "line 8, in 
    sum=(sum + freq[i])/i
IndexError: list index out of range"

however when I start the range from zero: `for i in range(121)` and remove the i in the denominator of `sum=sum + freq[i]` the program works fine.

I don't understand how does it see that the index is out of range when there is no zero in the list while it works when there is a zero??

Comment: Lists start at index `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this syntax (you didn't specify the language in tags), but when you start from 1, not from 0, there is no `freq[1]`, because when you add the first element to `freq[]` its index is probably 0 (depends on the language, but it seems it works like it here), so first element is `freq[0]`.

You can try `freq[i-1]` if you want to keep this `for` construction.

Answer (score 2):

When you start iterating from i=1 then:

```
freq.append(cos(2*pi*i*(x/8001)))
sum=(sum + freq[1])/i   => freq[1] (index out of range)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is initialized as an empty list. During the first iteration you append an item, giving value to `freq[0]`. However, since your loop starts at `i=1`, and it tries to access `freq[1]`, an error occurs because there's no `freq[1]` yet.

There's no error when you start the range at zero because during the first iteration (`i=0`) `freq[0]` exists.

Comment: does this mean that no matter what I put in the loop, the index of the list will always start from zero?